# Slim4 - getHeader is returning empty

Tags: php, postman, http-headers, slim-4

I am getting an empty array from slim4 `$request->getHeader('accept')` method to do checksum authorization. Also `$request->getParsedBody()` is working fine. I followed the code from documentation like below:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Application\Actions\Users;

use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface;
use Psr\Http\Server\RequestHandlerInterface;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Slim\Psr7\Response;
use Cake\Validation\Validator;
use Selective\Validation\ValidationResult;
use Selective\Validation\Factory\CakeValidationFactory;
use Selective\Validation\Exception\ValidationException;
use PDO;
use \Firebase\JWT\JWT;
use App\Application\Helpers\CommonHelper;

class ChangePwdAction implements RequestHandlerInterface
{
    private $logger;
    private $connection;

    public function __construct(PDO $connection,LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        $this->connection = $connection;
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    public function handle(ServerRequestInterface $request): ResponseInterface
    {
        echo $request->getHeader('userId');exit;
    }
}
```

**API Call**:

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use App\Application\Actions\Users\ListUserAction;
use App\Application\Actions\Users\ChangePwdAction;
$app->group('/v1/user', function (Group $group) {
        $group->get('', ListUserAction::class);
        $group->post('/changePwd/{id}', ChangePwdAction::class);
    });
```

[image: Postman request call]

**LOG Results and empty array**:
[image: LOG Result]

Comment: I'd start by fixing the 500 error you are getting there.

Comment: @CBroe - updated the post with log result - an empty array

Comment: You should not be using a header named `userId` to begin with. The convention is to start any custom header names, that are not defined by any standard / RFC, with the prefix `X-`, so if anything, you should be sending something like `X-User-Id` here. (Maybe the framework or the server "filters out" such headers that break convention?)

Comment: @CBroe - I tried to pass and receive 'X-User-Id', still getting the same error

Comment: Try and dump the whole `$request->headers`, and see what that gets you. You could also dump $_SERVER, and see what you get in there. If this header has not even made it so far that it reaches your application, it might have been filtered out (or rewritten to a different name) by PHP / the web server before already.

Comment: @CBroe - both $request->getHeaders() and $_SERVER methods are returning an empty array. I am new for PHP. So couldn't found the exact issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use $request->getHeader('userId')[0]